# How to convert from Hijri Date to Georgian Date and vice versa

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, hijri

I am looking for a way to calculate for example how many days it is from now, to a specific Date AND that I can use to determine whether I am in a specific time period (eg. Muharram +- 5days) or not

I have been looking for over 10hours now, and the best things I found were the "HijrahDate" library "java.time.chrono.HijrahDate" and something called "Joda Date", which I had difficulties to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Which variation of Hijri calendar do you want to use?**

If you opt for the official calendar of Saudi-Arabia then the solution based on [java.time.HijrahDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/HijrahDate.html) would work. But this class requires at least API level 26 on Android. Example:

```
HijrahDate hd1 = HijrahDate.now();
HijrahDate hd2 = HijrahDate.from(LocalDate.of(2020, 5, 1));
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(hd1, hd2);
```

There are also comparison methods like `isAfter()` or `isBefore()` inherited from the interface `ChronoLocalDate` and standard plus()-methods in order to determine if your date is in a specific time period.

**Backport of `java.time`:**

There is also a backport called [ThreetenABP](https://github.com/jakewharton/threetenabp) for lower Android-versions. But be aware of the pitfall that its implementation of `HijrahDate` is different and does NOT use the calendar of Saudi-Arabia (so you have to tolerate differences in date conversion).

**About Joda-Time:**

If you opt for that (rather outdated) library then you should choose the library version [adapted for android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android). However, it does not support the calendar of Saudi-Arabia, too, but offers four different other variations. You would need to specify the algorithmic [leap year pattern](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/chrono/IslamicChronology.LeapYearPatternType.html).

**ICU4J (embedded in Android):**

Its class [IslamicCalendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/util/IslamicCalendar) offers a style similar to old calendar classes `java.util.Calendar` and also several variants including that of Saudi-Arabia. The minimum required API level is 24.

**Time4A:**

That is a library written by myself (as [adaptation of Time4J for Android](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A)). It offers the class [HijriCalendar](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/HijriCalendar.html) with several variations including the Joda-variants but also including the calendar of Saudi-Arabia (variant ummalqura). It offers all needed features like date arithmetic (by plus()- or minus()-method), date comparison (by isAfter() etc.). Example:

```
String variant = HijriCalendar.VARIANT_UMALQURA;
StartOfDay startOfDay = StartOfDay.definedBy(SolarTime.ofMecca().sunset());
HijriCalendar today = HijriCalendar.nowInSystemTime(variant, startOfDay);
HijriCalendar hcal = // gregorian to Hijri conversion
    PlainDate.of(2020, 5, 1).transform(HijriCalendar.class, variant);
long days = CalendarDays.between(today, hcal).getAmount();
```

Features like sunset as start of day are not supported by other libraries. Example for your Muharram +- 5days-request might look like:

```
CalendarDays tolerance = CalendarDays.of(5);
HijriCalendar htemp = today.with(HijriCalendar.MONTH_OF_YEAR, HijriMonth.MUHARRAM);
HijriCalendar h1 = htemp.with(HijriCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH.minimized()).minus(tolerance);
HijriCalendar h2 = htemp.with(HijriCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH.maximized()).plus(tolerance);
boolean inTimePeriod = !(today.isBefore(h1) || today.isAfter(h2));
```

Comment: Thanks but for example if I want to know what 1.7.1441 is in the Georgian Calendar, which command would I have to use if I'm trying to do this with "Hijrahdate" (date conversion that I meant)?

Comment: @Visonge In `java.time`: `LocalDate.from(HijrahDate.of(1441, 7, 1));` (and in Time4A: `HijriCalendar.ofUmalqura(1441, 7, 1).transform(PlainDate.class)`)

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
HijrahDate
.from
(
    LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) 
)
.plus
(
    Period.ofDays( 5 ) 
)
.isBefore
(
    someOtherDate
)
```

## Details

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later, and Android 26 and later. For earlier versions, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects.

The *Joda-Time* project is the predecessor of *java.time*. Both are founded and led by the same man, Stephen Colebourne.

The [`HijrahChronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/chrono/HijrahChronology.html#date(int,int,int)) is part of *java.time*. The `HijrahChronology` follows the rules of the Hijrah calendar system. The Hijrah calendar is a lunar calendar supporting Islamic calendars.

The [`HijrahDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/chrono/HijrahDate.html) class represents a date in the Hijrah calendar system.

Search Stack Overflow to learn more, as this has been covered multiple times already.

I am not an expert on Islamic calendars or `HijrahChronology`, but I believe you can convert between a Hijrah date and a Gregorian (proleptic) date by calling the `from` method on `HijrahDate` and `LocalDate` classes.

```
LocalDate localDate1 = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
HijrahDate hijrahDate = HijrahDate.from( localDate1 ) ;
```

…and…

```
LocalDate localDate2 = LocalDate.from( hijrahDate ) ;
```

Both date classes offer `plus` and `minus` methods that take a `Period` object.

```
LocalDate later = localDate2.plus( Period.ofDays( 5 ) ) ;
```

Compare with `isEqual`, `isBefore`, and `isAfter`.

```
boolean match = localDate1.isEqual( localDate2 ) ;
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "localDate1.toString(): " + localDate1 ) ;
System.out.println( "hijrahDate.toString(): " + hijrahDate ) ;
System.out.println( "localDate2.toString(): " + localDate2 ) ;
System.out.println( "match: " + localDate1.isEqual( localDate2 ) ) ;
System.out.println( "later.toString(): " + later ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/dxJNeb).

> localDate1.toString(): 2020-01-23
>
> hijrahDate.toString(): Hijrah-umalqura AH 1441-05-28
>
> localDate2.toString(): 2020-01-23
>
> match: true
>
> later.toString(): 2020-01-28

Here is a complete example. The comparison method for a span-of-time used here is Half-Open, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This approach is usually best in date-time handling. This approach lets date ranges neatly abut one another without gaps or overlaps.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 23 );
HijrahDate hijrahDate = HijrahDate.from( localDate );

// Target range is five days before and after some specific date.
HijrahDate target = HijrahDate.from( LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.MARCH , 14 ) );
Period period = Period.ofDays( 5 );
LocalDate start = LocalDate.from( target ).minus( period );
LocalDate end = LocalDate.from( target ).plus( period );

// Tip: A shorter way of asking "Is equal to or later" is "Is not before".
boolean withinTargetRange = ( ! hijrahDate.isBefore( start ) ) && hijrahDate.isBefore( end );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "localDate = " + localDate );
System.out.println( "hijrahDate = " + hijrahDate );
System.out.println( "target = " + target );
System.out.println( "withinTargetRange = " + withinTargetRange );
```

> localDate = 2020-01-23
>
> hijrahDate = Hijrah-umalqura AH 1441-05-28
>
> target = Hijrah-umalqura AH 1441-07-19
>
> withinTargetRange = false

## *ThreeTen-Extra*

If doing much of this work, I suggest adding the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library, also founded and led by Stephen Colebourne. The `LocalDateRange` class in that library represents a span of time as a pair of `LocalDate` objects. This class includes methods such as `contains`, `abuts`, `overlaps`, and more. I do not know how well this library works in Android. If not working well in Android, you may want to pull a copy of the class’s source code into your codebase, provided you can abide by the terms of [its BSD-3 licensing](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/licenses.html).

Here is an example using [`LocalDateRange::contains`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html#contains(java.time.LocalDate)).

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 23 );
HijrahDate hijrahDate = HijrahDate.from( localDate );

HijrahDate target = HijrahDate.from( LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.MARCH , 14 ) );
Period period = Period.ofDays( 5 );
LocalDate start = LocalDate.from( target ).minus( period );
LocalDate end = LocalDate.from( target ).plus( period );
LocalDateRange range = LocalDateRange.of( start , end );

boolean withinTargetRange = range.contains( LocalDate.from( hijrahDate ) );
```

```
localDate = 2020-01-23
hijrahDate = Hijrah-umalqura AH 1441-05-28
target = Hijrah-umalqura AH 1441-07-19
range = 2020-03-09/2020-03-19
withinTargetRange = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Understand that dates and times are represented internally in computers as an offset from an epoch: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)

In Java, you can get this value using System.currentTimeMillis();

You can also calculate day difference my substracting two date numbers and applying division to do unit conversion.

```
long days = (date2 - date1) 
  / 1000 // MS
  / 60 // Secs
  / 60 // Mins
  / 24 // Hours
```