# JodaTime (Java): Hijri to Gregorian conversion inaccurate?

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime, hijri

I am currently implementing a calendar converter which, given a Hijri input date and time, outputs the corresponding Gregorian date and time using the `JodaTime` library. However, the corresponding Gregorian time is not accurate. No matter what Hijri time I input in the same day, the resulting Gregorian date is the same. This seems strange, considering that each Hijri day spans two Gregorian days, sunset to sunset, as stated in this answer (https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/71850/can-a-day-in-the-gregorian-calendar-correspond-to-two-different-days-in-the-isla).

For example, below is the code which converts from a Hijri DateTime (current day, can specify a different time in the day) to the corresponding Gregorian DateTime:

```
Chronology iso = ISOChronology.getInstanceUTC();
Chronology hijri = IslamicChronology.getInstanceUTC();

DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
int year = currentDate.getYear();
int month = currentDate.getMonthOfYear();
int day = currentDate.getDayOfMonth();

int customHr = 23;
int customMin = 59;
int customSec = 59;

DateTime todayIso = new DateTime(year, month, day, customHr, customMin, customSec, 0, iso);
LocalDateTime todayHijri = new LocalDateTime(todayIso, hijri);
System.out.println(todayHijri.toString());
```

Below are the results:

```
Hijri DateTime Input: 8/24/2021 at final second (23:59)
Gregorian DateTime Output: 1443-01-15T23:59:59.000

Hijri DateTime Input: 8/24/2021 at first second (0:01)
Gregorian DateTime Output: 1443-01-15T00:00:01.000
```

However, when I run this piece of code which converts from a Gregorian DateTime to a Hijri DateTime:

```
Chronology hijri = IslamicChronology.getInstanceUTC();

int customHour = 0;
int customMin = 0;
int customSec = 1;

DateTime todayIso = new DateTime(2021, 8, 24, customHour, customMin, customSec);
LocalDateTime todayHijri = new LocalDateTime(todayIso, hijri);
System.out.println(todayHijri);
```

These are the results I get, using the outputs of the Gregorian to Hijri conversion as inputs. As you can see the outputted Hijri DateTimes are **different** than the input Hijri DateTimes in the Hijri to Gregorian conversion, which means something is wrong.

```
Gregorian DateTime Input: 8-24-2021 at 0:01
Hijri DateTime Output: 1443-01-15T07:00:01.000

Gregorian DateTime Input: 8-24-2021 at 23:59:59
Hijri DateTime Output: 1443-01-16T06:59:59.000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_islamic.html

> **A day in the Islamic calendar begins at sunset on the previous 'day'. Joda-Time does not model this, thus times and date rollover follow standard ISO definitions, in other words starting at midnight**

As [Joda-Time is in maintenance](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time),

See: [How to convert from Hijri Date to Georgian Date and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61503812/295004) for options.

Comment: Are there any possible solutions to this problem?

Comment: @AdamLee Updated answer with context & link to more expansive SO post.

Comment: [The TIme4J library](http://time4j.net/) contains support for a solution (there may be other libraries that do, I don’t know).

Comment: @MorrisonChang So I checked out the more expansive SO post and it seems that the answers there deals with date conversion, but didn't include times (e.g. 11:50 PM), which is a capability that is central to my calendar conversion app.

Comment: @AdamLee Have you tried [Time4A as mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61508728/295004)? Also when in doubt, check if  [related github issues existed](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed+sunset)